# When Do Data Binding Methods Fire After Layout Inflation?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-databinding

I'm using data binding and I'm running into an issue where a view property that I bind to is not being populated immediately after the layout is inflated and the view model is set for the binding class.

In the containing Fragment I use BindingUtil to inflate the bound layout in the Fragment's onCreateView(). I then immediately set the binding variable which is my view model.

However, when I debug right after setting the binding's view model the layout has nulls for some of the view's properties I've bound to the view model. If I wait a fraction of a second the properties will be set via binding as expected.

Thus, when does the actual binding of the view's properties occur? I assumed it occurred as soon as the view model was set to the binding class. This must be wrong...

Can someone help me with a sound way to debug this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per the [Data Binding documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#immediate_binding):

> When a variable or observable changes, the binding will be scheduled to change before the next frame. There are times, however, when binding must be executed immediately. To force execution, use the [executePendingBindings()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ViewDataBinding.html#executePendingBindings()) method.

Comment: This apply to inflation? I suppose I should try to execute that method in onCreateView(). Thanks

Comment: Right: Data Binding batches all calls to the next frame by default (this prevents it from doing extra work if you call it multiple times in the same frame).

Comment: Awesome, this fixed my issue!

Comment: but does the data binding trigger once the view is created or only when you post the value? For example if I have a text res ID that is data bound, will it pull from this data on creation even before I post the value?